# Regex to validate a semi-colon separated list of emails?

Tags: c#, regex, validation, email, csv

I have the following c# extension method for validating an email address.  The regex came from Microsoft on their 'How to: Verify that Strings Are in Valid Email Format' page.

I need to improve this method to be able to handle a semi-colon separated list of emails. A valid example string could be as badly formatted as: `";;  ; ;  xxx.sss.xxx ; ;; xxx.sss.xxx;"`

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Validates the string is an Email Address...
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="emailAddress"></param>
    /// <returns>bool</returns>
    public static bool IsValidEmailAddress(this string emailAddress)
    {
        var valid = true;
        var isnotblank = false;

        var email = emailAddress.Trim();
        if (email.Length > 0)
        {
            isnotblank = true;
            valid = Regex.IsMatch(email, @"^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" +
            @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        }

        return (valid && isnotblank);
    }
```

Comment: For a really easy way to check an email address is valid, please see the note at the end of that MSDN example: "Instead of using a regular expression to validate an email address, you can use the System.Net.Mail.MailAddress class. To determine whether an email address is valid, pass the email address to the MailAddress.MailAddress(String) class constructor."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft's regex does a pretty good job.  However, it doesn't catch a few strange scenarios and a number of special characters which are valid for email.  I'll give you a different regex.  Choose to use it or not is your prerogative.

I would separate the concerns by having one extension method which validates an email address and another which validates the list.  Do a .trim() on each email before passing it to the email validation method.  So, something like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Validates the string is an Email Address...
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="emailAddress"></param>
    /// <returns>bool</returns>
    public static bool IsValidEmailAddress(this string emailAddress)
    {
        var valid = true;
        var isnotblank = false;

        var email = emailAddress.Trim();
        if (email.Length > 0)
        {
            // Email Address Cannot start with period.
            // Name portion must be at least one character
            // In the Name, valid characters are:  a-z 0-9 ! # _ % & ' " = ` { } ~ - + * ? ^ | / $
            // Cannot have period immediately before @ sign.
            // Cannot have two @ symbols
            // In the domain, valid characters are: a-z 0-9 - .
            // Domain cannot start with a period or dash
            // Domain name must be 2 characters.. not more than 256 characters
            // Domain cannot end with a period or dash.
            // Domain must contain a period
            isnotblank = true;
            valid = Regex.IsMatch(email, @"\A([\w!#%&'""=`{}~\.\-\+\*\?\^\|\/\$])+@{1}\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*\z", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) &&
                !email.StartsWith("-") &&
                !email.StartsWith(".") &&
                !email.EndsWith(".") && 
                !email.Contains("..") &&
                !email.Contains(".@") &&
                !email.Contains("@.");
        }

        return (valid && isnotblank);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Validates the string is an Email Address or a delimited string of email addresses...
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="emailAddress"></param>
    /// <returns>bool</returns>
    public static bool IsValidEmailAddressDelimitedList(this string emailAddress, char delimiter = ';')
    {
        var valid = true;
        var isnotblank = false;

        string[] emails = emailAddress.Split(delimiter);

        foreach (string e in emails)
        {
            var email = e.Trim();
            if (email.Length > 0 && valid) // if valid == false, no reason to continue checking
            {
                isnotblank = true;
                if (!email.IsValidEmailAddress())
                {
                    valid = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return (valid && isnotblank);
    }
```

Comment: You could simplify the list validation with: `if (!email.IsValidEmailAddress()) return false;` because there is no point to go on with the for loop in that case. The final return becomes `return isnotblank;` and the `valid` variable can be dropped.

Comment: Yeah.  I did that just so I could drop a break point in there.  I do that a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to allow several emails separated by semicolon and (optionally) spaces besides the semicolon. It will also accept single email address that does not end in semicolon.

Right now it allows empty entries as well(no email addresses). If You wanna change it to have at least 1, then replace  the final * by + to require at least one address.

```
(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)(\s*;\s*|\s*$))*
```

If you want to allow comma as well as semicolon, you can chage following :

```
(\s*;\s*|\s*$)
```

to this:

```
(\s*(;|,)\s*|\s*$)
```

Comment: This works for the semi-colon delimination.  But, email addresses have far more complex requirements.  There are about 14 special characters that your regex is not matching on.  Also, emails cannot start or end with periods or dashes.  And the @ symbol cannot have peroids before or after.